# create embedded forms in django view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a rule class, a rule is a combination of a question and an answer:

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    rule_id = models.ForeignKey(Rule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    rule_id = models.ForeignKey(Rule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to create a form for the rule, where I have two inputs: one for the question and the other for answer. When I click submit I should save a rule in rule table, a question in question table and an answer in answer table. This is the farest I get: I created a form for each model, and I called those forms in one view method:

```
def create_rule_view(request,id, sc_id):
    rule = RuleForm(request.POST or None)
    question= QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
    answer = AnswerForm(request.POST or None)
    if rule.is_valid() and question.is_valid() and answer.is_valid():
        rule.save()
        question.save()
        answer.save()
        return redirect('../')
    context = {
        'rule': rule,
        'question': question,
        'answer': answer
    }
    return render(request, "rule/create_rule.html", context)
```

But it's not the view I want and each model is saved independantly. Can anyone find a solution for me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add these fields to RuleForm like this, and override the `save` method to save them:

```
class RuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question = forms.CharField(required=True)
    answer = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Rule
       fields=['name', 'question', 'answer']

    def save(self, commit=False):
       question = self.cleaned_data.pop('question')
       answer = self.cleaned_data.pop('answer') 
       rule = super(RuleForm, self).save(commit=True)
       Question.objects.create(rule=rule, name=question)
       Answer.objects.create(rule=rule, name=answer)
       return rule
```

Now, all you need to pass the Rule Form in view:

```
def create_rule_view(request,id, sc_id):
    rule = RuleForm(request.POST or None)
    if rule.is_valid():
        rule.save()
        return redirect('../')
    context = {
        'rule': rule,
    }
    return render(request, "rule/create_rule.html", context)
```

Comment: I don't have question and answer in rule class. shall I add them too?

Comment: you don't need to. You will be adding extra fields in form.

Comment: Maybe this can help me for now. But what if I added more fields in the answer? Like some links or images?

Comment: I am afraid you need to add these fields manually to the RuleForm. But there are some libraries you can look into for using multiple form togather, like this one: https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html